# Como Carregar RichEdit Linha por Linha A partir de Arquivo

Tags: delphi

Preciso carregar um RichEdit a partir de um arquivo .txt lendo linha por linha.

Estou utilizando um código, porém o RichEdit não carrega caracteres com acento (Exemplos: ç, à, á, ã, é, ê, í, ô, õ, ó, ú...)

O código é o seguinte:

```
procedure TFrmMain.AbrirTxtNovo;
var
   MyOpenDialog : TOpenDialog;
   MyTextFile : TextFile;
   Linha : String;
begin
MyOpenDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(self);
MyOpenDialog.Filter := 'Arquivos Texto|*.txt';
MyOpenDialog.InitialDir := 'C:\';
MyOpenDialog.Title := ' Selecione um arquivo para leitura ';

If (MyOpenDialog.Execute) And (Length (MyOpenDialog.FileName) > 0) then
   begin
   AssignFile (MyTextFile, MyOpenDialog.FileName);
   Reset (MyTextFile);
   RichEdit.ScrollBars := ssBoth; // Permito exibição das Scroolbars
   RichEdit.Lines.Clear; // Limpo o RichEdit
   RichEdit.Font.Name := 'Arial'; // Ajusto a fonte para Arial
   RichEdit.WordWrap := False; // Evito quebra na linha

   while not (Eof (MyTextFile)) do
      begin
      ReadLn (MyTextFile, Linha);
      RichEdit.Lines.Add (LimpaString (Linha));
      end;

   CloseFile (MyTextFile);
   end
else
   Application.MessageBox(PChar ('Erro ao tentar ler o arquivo!' +
   MyOpenDialog.FileName), 'Erro na abertura do arquivo', mb_Ok);

end;
```

A função LimpaString

```
function LimpaString (strIN: String): String;
var
   Counter : Integer;
   strOUT : String;
begin
   for Counter := 1 to Length (strIN) do
   if (Ord (strIN[Counter]) >= 032) and (Ord (strIN[Counter]) <= 125) then
       strOUT := strOUT + strIN[Counter];

Result := strOUT;
end;
```

Como solucionar esse problema?

Comment: mas se fizer RichEdit.Lines.Add('aéó'); funciona, certo?
E o ficheiro tem tags the richtext ou é só texto simples?

Comment: Bom dia #Lucasmb.. tudo certinho?? :) Cara estou usando delphi 7.. Peguei o seu código e coloquei aqui e funcionou tudo direitinho.. Criei um arquivo texto com as seguintes palavras..:Maça ação má lá ló Tú e foram importadas corretamente pelo seu código. A única coisa que não consegui replicar foi a FUNÇÃO LimpaString. Então rodei o seu código sem ela.  Se o código é somente esse.. Então quem sabe o problema não é o arquivo .TXT.. Disponibiliza ele que eu importo aqui.. a Função LimpaString também..Qualquer coisa é só falar :)

Comment: Olá @RicardoM.Souza Tinha esquecido de mencionar a function LimpaString (que agora foi citada na pergunta) e é realmente esta function que está "limpando" os acentos do txt. Retirei e funcionou. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Olá @TiagoRodrigues estou usando o RichEdit.Lines.Add('...') e está funcionando certo. Obrigado.